# PHP's =& operator

Tags: php, assignment-operator

Are both these PHP statements doing the same thing?:

```
$o =& $thing;

$o = &$thing;
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, they are both the exact same thing. They just take the reference of the object and reference it within the variable `$o`.  Please note, `thing` should be variables.

Comment: Yes, sorry I did mean `$thing`.

Answer (score 30):

They're not the same thing, syntactically speaking. The operator is the atomic **=&** and this actually matters. For instance you can't use the **=&** operator in a ternary expression. Neither of the following are valid syntax:

```
$f = isset($field[0]) ? &$field[0] : &$field;
$f =& isset($field[0]) ? $field[0] : $field;
```

So instead you would use this:

```
isset($field[0]) ? $f =& $field[0] : $f =& $field;
```

Comment: I was hoping to find some documentation to confirm this, however php.net isn't very clear. [What references do](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) mentions `=&`, but, oddly, `=&` doesn't actually apear in the [assignment operators](http://php.net//manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) (it's always `$x = &$y;`). Is the white space really significant or are these identical? Can you provide some references?

Comment: If the PHP folks wanted, they could modify the PHP parser to allow the second bad example above, but it looks like the =& combination is interpreted by the preprocessor and not at runtime. If you peek at the source code of the PHP compiler/interpreter you can confirm this.

Answer (score 13):

They both give an expected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM error.

If you meant `$o = &$thing;` then that assigns the reference of thing to o. Here's an example:

```
$thing = "foo";

$o = &$thing;

echo $o; // echos foo

$thing = "bar";

echo $o; // echos bar
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I did mean `$thing`.

Answer (score 12):

The difference is very important:

```
<?php
$a = "exists";
$b = $a;
$c =& $a;
echo "a=".$a.", b=".$b.", c=".$c."<br/>"; //a=exists b=exists c=exists

$a = null;
echo "a=".$a.", b=".$b.", c=".$c; //a= b=exists c= 
?>
```

Variable $c dies as $a becomes NULL, but variable $b keeps its value.

Comment: That's not what the (current edit) of the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do. `$o` will become a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference) to `thing` in both cases (I assume that `thing` is not a constant, but actually something meaningful as a variable).

Comment: You don't reference functions like that, nor can you reference constants.

Comment: Karl, I assumed that thing was NOT a constant since references to constants are pointless. You are correct about the functions though.

Comment: Yes, sorry I did mean `$thing`.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, it was an answer to a former version which was errorenous forulated

please delete this

Answer (score 1):

If you meant `thing` with a `$` before them, then yes, both are assigning by reference. You can learn more about references in PHP here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: Yes, sorry I did mean `$thing`.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, it was an answer to a former version which was errorenous forulated

please delete this