# Build multidimensional from single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**Outline**

After spending 2 days trying to get this to work...

**Solution**

I would like to restructure my array into a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
 Level 1 -> All level 1s
       Level 2 -> All level 2s
               Level 3 -> Each level Three Item
               Level 3 -> Each level Three Item
       Level 2 -> All level 2s
               Level 3 -> Each level Three Item
               Level 3 -> Each level Three Item
 Level 1 -> All level 1s
       Level 2 -> All level 2s
               Level 3 -> Each level Three Item
               Level 3 -> Each level Three Item
       Level 2 -> All level 2s
               Level 3 -> Each level Three Item
               Level 3 -> Each level Three Item
```

**Data**

The data is written in the order that I need it to be. For example, all `level 2` directly below a `Level 1` should site within its parent `Level 1` until the next `Level 1` turns up in the data. This should be the same for `Level 2` and `3`. Basically until a higher number comes along, it should that start a new row.

I have many different values, the data below is just an example. Inside the array `level` refers which level it should sit under.

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'key' => 0,
        'id' => '7',
        'level' => '1',
        'name' => 'About Me',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'key' => 1,
        'id' => '78',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'My Conduct at Work',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'key' => 2,
        'id' => '270',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Dispute Resolution/Grievance',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        'key' => 3,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        'key' => 4,
        'id' => '77',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'My Environment, Health & Safety',
      ),
      5 => 
      array (
        'key' => 5,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      6 => 
      array (
        'key' => 6,
        'id' => '238',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Policies and Guidance',
      ),
      7 => 
      array (
        'key' => 7,
        'id' => '79',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'My GSK Employment Journey',
      ),
      8 => 
      array (
        'key' => 8,
        'id' => '274',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Changes in Role',
      ),
      9 => 
      array (
        'key' => 9,
        'id' => '275',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Leaving GSK',
      ),
      10 => 
      array (
        'key' => 10,
        'id' => '273',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'My Moves',
      ),
      11 => 
      array (
        'key' => 11,
        'id' => '272',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Starting at GSK',
      ),
      12 => 
      array (
        'key' => 12,
        'id' => '80',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'My Personal Information',
      ),
      13 => 
      array (
        'key' => 13,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      14 => 
      array (
        'key' => 14,
        'id' => '276',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Manage my Personal Information',
      ),
      15 => 
      array (
        'key' => 15,
        'id' => '76',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'My Talent, Performance & Development',
      ),
      16 => 
      array (
        'key' => 16,
        'id' => '266',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'My Development',
      ),
      17 => 
      array (
        'key' => 17,
        'id' => '268',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'My Learning',
      ),
      18 => 
      array (
        'key' => 18,
        'id' => '267',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'My Performance',
      ),
      19 => 
      array (
        'key' => 19,
        'id' => '75',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'My TotalReward',
      ),
      20 => 
      array (
        'key' => 20,
        'id' => '287',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More My Benefits',
      ),
      21 => 
      array (
        'key' => 21,
        'id' => '288',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More My Pay',
      ),
      22 => 
      array (
        'key' => 22,
        'id' => '264',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'My Benefits',
      ),
      23 => 
      array (
        'key' => 23,
        'id' => '263',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'My Pay',
      ),
      24 => 
      array (
        'key' => 24,
        'id' => '265',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'My Recognition',
      ),
      25 => 
      array (
        'key' => 25,
        'id' => '81',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Time Off, Time & Attendance',
      ),
      26 => 
      array (
        'key' => 26,
        'id' => '281',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Flexible Working',
      ),
      27 => 
      array (
        'key' => 27,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      28 => 
      array (
        'key' => 28,
        'id' => '279',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Leave of Absence',
      ),
      29 => 
      array (
        'key' => 29,
        'id' => '280',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Time & Attendance',
      ),
      30 => 
      array (
        'key' => 30,
        'id' => '278',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Time Off',
      ),
      31 => 
      array (
        'key' => 31,
        'id' => '1',
        'level' => '1',
        'name' => 'Buying and Paying',
      ),
      32 => 
      array (
        'key' => 32,
        'id' => '1',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Budget Management',
      ),
      33 => 
      array (
        'key' => 33,
        'id' => '1',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Asset scrapping or sale (equipment, PC â€¦)',
      ),
      34 => 
      array (
        'key' => 34,
        'id' => '221',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Cost center creation & change',
      ),
      35 => 
      array (
        'key' => 35,
        'id' => '2',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Finance Partner',
      ),
      36 => 
      array (
        'key' => 36,
        'id' => '3',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Operating Budget',
      ),
      37 => 
      array (
        'key' => 37,
        'id' => '222',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Provision request',
      ),
      38 => 
      array (
        'key' => 38,
        'id' => '4',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'X-charge (Cost Transfer)',
      ),
      39 => 
      array (
        'key' => 39,
        'id' => '3',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Checks, GOA & X-Charge',
      ),
      40 => 
      array (
        'key' => 40,
        'id' => '10',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Check Requests',
      ),
      41 => 
      array (
        'key' => 41,
        'id' => '11',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Collections, credits and debts',
      ),
      42 => 
      array (
        'key' => 42,
        'id' => '12',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Discounts, Rebates, Commissions and Allowances',
      ),
      43 => 
      array (
        'key' => 43,
        'id' => '217',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Grant of Authority',
      ),
      44 => 
      array (
        'key' => 44,
        'id' => '4',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'X-charge (Cost Transfer)',
      ),
      45 => 
      array (
        'key' => 45,
        'id' => '6',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Finance for Finance',
      ),
      46 => 
      array (
        'key' => 46,
        'id' => '241',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Finance Assurance',
      ),
      47 => 
      array (
        'key' => 47,
        'id' => '22',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Order to Cash',
      ),
      48 => 
      array (
        'key' => 48,
        'id' => '23',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'R2R - Group Consolidation and Intercompany Profit',
      ),
      49 => 
      array (
        'key' => 49,
        'id' => '24',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'R2R - Management Reporting',
      ),
      50 => 
      array (
        'key' => 50,
        'id' => '25',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'R2R - Record, Forms & Reports',
      ),
      51 => 
      array (
        'key' => 51,
        'id' => '251',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'R2R - Record, General Information',
      ),
      52 => 
      array (
        'key' => 52,
        'id' => '252',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'R2R - Record, Get Help',
      ),
      53 => 
      array (
        'key' => 53,
        'id' => '26',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'R2R - Statutory Reporting',
      ),
      54 => 
      array (
        'key' => 54,
        'id' => '27',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'R2R - Technical Accounting',
      ),
      55 => 
      array (
        'key' => 55,
        'id' => '28',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Supply Chain Accounting',
      ),
      56 => 
      array (
        'key' => 56,
        'id' => '65',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Invoice and Supplier Services',
      ),
      57 => 
      array (
        'key' => 57,
        'id' => '13',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Invoice and Supplier Services',
      ),
      58 => 
      array (
        'key' => 58,
        'id' => '93',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Mergers, Acquisitions and Divestments Support',
      ),
      59 => 
      array (
        'key' => 59,
        'id' => '317',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Engage with MAD',
      ),
      60 => 
      array (
        'key' => 60,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      61 => 
      array (
        'key' => 61,
        'id' => '66',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Procurement Card',
      ),
      62 => 
      array (
        'key' => 62,
        'id' => '14',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Procurement Card Program',
      ),
      63 => 
      array (
        'key' => 63,
        'id' => '10',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Procurement for Procurement',
      ),
      64 => 
      array (
        'key' => 64,
        'id' => '49',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Contract Management',
      ),
      65 => 
      array (
        'key' => 65,
        'id' => '50',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Market Intelligence/Research Portal',
      ),
      66 => 
      array (
        'key' => 66,
        'id' => '325',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Procurement Training',
      ),
      67 => 
      array (
        'key' => 67,
        'id' => '51',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Risk Management',
      ),
      68 => 
      array (
        'key' => 68,
        'id' => '52',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Spend Analytics',
      ),
      69 => 
      array (
        'key' => 69,
        'id' => '53',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Supplier Diversity & Development Support',
      ),
      70 => 
      array (
        'key' => 70,
        'id' => '54',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Supplier Relationship & Performance Management',
      ),
      71 => 
      array (
        'key' => 71,
        'id' => '64',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Purchases',
      ),
      72 => 
      array (
        'key' => 72,
        'id' => '9',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Buy Something',
      ),
      73 => 
      array (
        'key' => 73,
        'id' => '259',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn About',
      ),
      74 => 
      array (
        'key' => 74,
        'id' => '3',
        'level' => '1',
        'name' => 'Expenses & Travel',
      ),
      75 => 
      array (
        'key' => 75,
        'id' => '69',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Book a Flight',
      ),
      76 => 
      array (
        'key' => 76,
        'id' => '72',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Airline Reservations',
      ),
      77 => 
      array (
        'key' => 77,
        'id' => '71',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Book a Ground Transportaion',
      ),
      78 => 
      array (
        'key' => 78,
        'id' => '319',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Rail',
      ),
      79 => 
      array (
        'key' => 79,
        'id' => '76',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Taxi, Chauffeur & Limousine Services',
      ),
      80 => 
      array (
        'key' => 80,
        'id' => '70',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Book a Hotel',
      ),
      81 => 
      array (
        'key' => 81,
        'id' => '75',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Hotel Room Booking',
      ),
      82 => 
      array (
        'key' => 82,
        'id' => '67',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Credit Card',
      ),
      83 => 
      array (
        'key' => 83,
        'id' => '68',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Amex',
      ),
      84 => 
      array (
        'key' => 84,
        'id' => '13',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Expense Policies and Information',
      ),
      85 => 
      array (
        'key' => 85,
        'id' => '69',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Expense Policies',
      ),
      86 => 
      array (
        'key' => 86,
        'id' => '71',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'VAT Reclaim',
      ),
      87 => 
      array (
        'key' => 87,
        'id' => '68',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Report Expenses',
      ),
      88 => 
      array (
        'key' => 88,
        'id' => '70',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Report Expenses',
      ),
      89 => 
      array (
        'key' => 89,
        'id' => '15',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Travel Information',
      ),
      90 => 
      array (
        'key' => 90,
        'id' => '73',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Benefits Administration and Management (UK/US)',
      ),
      91 => 
      array (
        'key' => 91,
        'id' => '74',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Commuter Services/Shuttle Busses',
      ),
      92 => 
      array (
        'key' => 92,
        'id' => '77',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Health while travelling',
      ),
      93 => 
      array (
        'key' => 93,
        'id' => '320',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Travel Alerts',
      ),
      94 => 
      array (
        'key' => 94,
        'id' => '14',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Travel Insurances',
      ),
      95 => 
      array (
        'key' => 95,
        'id' => '65',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Loss and theft',
      ),
      96 => 
      array (
        'key' => 96,
        'id' => '66',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Material damages insurance',
      ),
      97 => 
      array (
        'key' => 97,
        'id' => '67',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Travel insurance for personal injury',
      ),
      98 => 
      array (
        'key' => 98,
        'id' => '4',
        'level' => '1',
        'name' => 'IT Services & Access',
      ),
      99 => 
      array (
        'key' => 99,
        'id' => '16',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Basic IT Access',
      ),
      100 => 
      array (
        'key' => 100,
        'id' => '78',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Getting an ID',
      ),
      101 => 
      array (
        'key' => 101,
        'id' => '254',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Remote Access Tokens',
      ),
      102 => 
      array (
        'key' => 102,
        'id' => '79',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Request Access',
      ),
      103 => 
      array (
        'key' => 103,
        'id' => '255',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Request Access - Unix, Linux, VAX, AS400',
      ),
      104 => 
      array (
        'key' => 104,
        'id' => '23',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Business Unit Systems',
      ),
      105 => 
      array (
        'key' => 105,
        'id' => '93',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Corporate Finance Systems',
      ),
      106 => 
      array (
        'key' => 106,
        'id' => '84',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Customer Relationship Management & Marketing Systems',
      ),
      107 => 
      array (
        'key' => 107,
        'id' => '120',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Discovery Systems',
      ),
      108 => 
      array (
        'key' => 108,
        'id' => '94',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Global Finance Systems',
      ),
      109 => 
      array (
        'key' => 109,
        'id' => '125',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'HH and EHS Systems',
      ),
      110 => 
      array (
        'key' => 110,
        'id' => '118',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'IT support for audits and inspections',
      ),
      111 => 
      array (
        'key' => 111,
        'id' => '127',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Legal & Procurement Systems',
      ),
      112 => 
      array (
        'key' => 112,
        'id' => '95',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Make MRP Services Systems',
      ),
      113 => 
      array (
        'key' => 113,
        'id' => '85',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Market and Sell systems',
      ),
      114 => 
      array (
        'key' => 114,
        'id' => '121',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Medical Systems',
      ),
      115 => 
      array (
        'key' => 115,
        'id' => '96',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Pack & Move Services Systems',
      ),
      116 => 
      array (
        'key' => 116,
        'id' => '86',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'PPV & Sales Reporting & Compliance Systems',
      ),
      117 => 
      array (
        'key' => 117,
        'id' => '122',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Pre-Clinical Systems',
      ),
      118 => 
      array (
        'key' => 118,
        'id' => '119',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Quality, Risk & Analytics Systems',
      ),
      119 => 
      array (
        'key' => 119,
        'id' => '312',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'SAP Commercial',
      ),
      120 => 
      array (
        'key' => 120,
        'id' => '128',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'SAP Manufacturing',
      ),
      121 => 
      array (
        'key' => 121,
        'id' => '129',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Supply Chain Planning Services Systems',
      ),
      122 => 
      array (
        'key' => 122,
        'id' => '123',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Test Lab Systems & Support',
      ),
      123 => 
      array (
        'key' => 123,
        'id' => '27',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Desk Phones, Smartphones & Tablets',
      ),
      124 => 
      array (
        'key' => 124,
        'id' => '110',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Desk Phone',
      ),
      125 => 
      array (
        'key' => 125,
        'id' => '111',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Fax',
      ),
      126 => 
      array (
        'key' => 126,
        'id' => '247',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'IP Phone Communicator Configuration',
      ),
      127 => 
      array (
        'key' => 127,
        'id' => '112',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'IP Phone Communicator Help & How To',
      ),
      128 => 
      array (
        'key' => 128,
        'id' => '104',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Mobile and Smart phones',
      ),
      129 => 
      array (
        'key' => 129,
        'id' => '250',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Ordering an IP Phone and Headsets',
      ),
      130 => 
      array (
        'key' => 130,
        'id' => '107',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Synchronization with MS Outlook',
      ),
      131 => 
      array (
        'key' => 131,
        'id' => '108',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Tablets',
      ),
      132 => 
      array (
        'key' => 132,
        'id' => '113',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Teleconference solution choice',
      ),
      133 => 
      array (
        'key' => 133,
        'id' => '114',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Video phone',
      ),
      134 => 
      array (
        'key' => 134,
        'id' => '109',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Wifi Guest for Smartphone',
      ),
      135 => 
      array (
        'key' => 135,
        'id' => '18',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'EMail and Collaboration',
      ),
      136 => 
      array (
        'key' => 136,
        'id' => '87',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Distribution lists',
      ),
      137 => 
      array (
        'key' => 137,
        'id' => '324',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Effective Collaboration',
      ),
      138 => 
      array (
        'key' => 138,
        'id' => '88',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Filtering spam',
      ),
      139 => 
      array (
        'key' => 139,
        'id' => '89',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Group mailbox',
      ),
      140 => 
      array (
        'key' => 140,
        'id' => '80',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Live Meeting',
      ),
      141 => 
      array (
        'key' => 141,
        'id' => '90',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Lotus Notes',
      ),
      142 => 
      array (
        'key' => 142,
        'id' => '81',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Office communicator',
      ),
      143 => 
      array (
        'key' => 143,
        'id' => '91',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Outlook Mailbox & calendar',
      ),
      144 => 
      array (
        'key' => 144,
        'id' => '92',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Securing email',
      ),
      145 => 
      array (
        'key' => 145,
        'id' => '83',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Videoconference',
      ),
      146 => 
      array (
        'key' => 146,
        'id' => '19',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Hardware',
      ),
      147 => 
      array (
        'key' => 147,
        'id' => '97',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Borrow hardware',
      ),
      148 => 
      array (
        'key' => 148,
        'id' => '98',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Buy Hardware',
      ),
      149 => 
      array (
        'key' => 149,
        'id' => '99',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Move hardware',
      ),
      150 => 
      array (
        'key' => 150,
        'id' => '100',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Protect computer',
      ),
      151 => 
      array (
        'key' => 151,
        'id' => '101',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Repair hardware',
      ),
      152 => 
      array (
        'key' => 152,
        'id' => '102',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Smartphone and Mobile Devices',
      ),
      153 => 
      array (
        'key' => 153,
        'id' => '103',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Upgrade computer',
      ),
      154 => 
      array (
        'key' => 154,
        'id' => '8',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'IT for IT',
      ),
      155 => 
      array (
        'key' => 155,
        'id' => '35',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Application Infrastructure Provisioning',
      ),
      156 => 
      array (
        'key' => 156,
        'id' => '216',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Application, Process and Data Integration',
      ),
      157 => 
      array (
        'key' => 157,
        'id' => '42',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Connect to or from External Partners',
      ),
      158 => 
      array (
        'key' => 158,
        'id' => '36',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Data Center Operations and Facilities',
      ),
      159 => 
      array (
        'key' => 159,
        'id' => '37',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Database Services',
      ),
      160 => 
      array (
        'key' => 160,
        'id' => '47',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Hosting Services',
      ),
      161 => 
      array (
        'key' => 161,
        'id' => '321',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Infrastructure Services',
      ),
      162 => 
      array (
        'key' => 162,
        'id' => '39',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'IT Audit and Risk',
      ),
      163 => 
      array (
        'key' => 163,
        'id' => '40',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Malicious Code Management',
      ),
      164 => 
      array (
        'key' => 164,
        'id' => '41',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Network Services',
      ),
      165 => 
      array (
        'key' => 165,
        'id' => '326',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Optimise Application Performance',
      ),
      166 => 
      array (
        'key' => 166,
        'id' => '28',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Printer, archiving & scanning',
      ),
      167 => 
      array (
        'key' => 167,
        'id' => '115',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Archiving',
      ),
      168 => 
      array (
        'key' => 168,
        'id' => '116',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Desk Printers',
      ),
      169 => 
      array (
        'key' => 169,
        'id' => '117',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Printing & scanning',
      ),
      170 => 
      array (
        'key' => 170,
        'id' => '74',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Remote Access Tokens',
      ),
      171 => 
      array (
        'key' => 171,
        'id' => '11',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Reporting and Data Management',
      ),
      172 => 
      array (
        'key' => 172,
        'id' => '55',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'BI/DW (Business Intelligence/Data Warehouse)',
      ),
      173 => 
      array (
        'key' => 173,
        'id' => '242',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Business Objects Application',
      ),
      174 => 
      array (
        'key' => 174,
        'id' => '56',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'CERPS Data Management Service (CDMO)',
      ),
      175 => 
      array (
        'key' => 175,
        'id' => '243',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Cognos Application',
      ),
      176 => 
      array (
        'key' => 176,
        'id' => '244',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Cognos Planning Application',
      ),
      177 => 
      array (
        'key' => 177,
        'id' => '245',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'DataStage Application',
      ),
      178 => 
      array (
        'key' => 178,
        'id' => '246',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'DataWarehouse Service',
      ),
      179 => 
      array (
        'key' => 179,
        'id' => '57',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'ONE Service',
      ),
      180 => 
      array (
        'key' => 180,
        'id' => '29',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Software',
      ),
      181 => 
      array (
        'key' => 181,
        'id' => '313',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Manage AIT',
      ),
      182 => 
      array (
        'key' => 182,
        'id' => '124',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Requesting or Removing Software',
      ),
      183 => 
      array (
        'key' => 183,
        'id' => '30',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Wi-Fi & internet',
      ),
      184 => 
      array (
        'key' => 184,
        'id' => '131',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'GSK network for business partners',
      ),
      185 => 
      array (
        'key' => 185,
        'id' => '132',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Wifi for visitors',
      ),
      186 => 
      array (
        'key' => 186,
        'id' => '133',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Wifi in the office',
      ),
      187 => 
      array (
        'key' => 187,
        'id' => '134',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Working from Home',
      ),
      188 => 
      array (
        'key' => 188,
        'id' => '135',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Working in the Office',
      ),
      189 => 
      array (
        'key' => 189,
        'id' => '5',
        'level' => '1',
        'name' => 'My Team',
      ),
      190 => 
      array (
        'key' => 190,
        'id' => '88',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Environment, Health & Safety',
      ),
      191 => 
      array (
        'key' => 191,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      192 => 
      array (
        'key' => 192,
        'id' => '89',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'My Teams\' Conduct at Work',
      ),
      193 => 
      array (
        'key' => 193,
        'id' => '296',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Code of Conduct',
      ),
      194 => 
      array (
        'key' => 194,
        'id' => '294',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Disciplinary',
      ),
      195 => 
      array (
        'key' => 195,
        'id' => '270',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Dispute Resolution/Grievance',
      ),
      196 => 
      array (
        'key' => 196,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      197 => 
      array (
        'key' => 197,
        'id' => '90',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'My Teams\' Employment Journey',
      ),
      198 => 
      array (
        'key' => 198,
        'id' => '301',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Changes',
      ),
      199 => 
      array (
        'key' => 199,
        'id' => '297',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Hiring',
      ),
      200 => 
      array (
        'key' => 200,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      201 => 
      array (
        'key' => 201,
        'id' => '275',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Leaving GSK',
      ),
      202 => 
      array (
        'key' => 202,
        'id' => '300',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Manage an International Assignment',
      ),
      203 => 
      array (
        'key' => 203,
        'id' => '141',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Onboarding',
      ),
      204 => 
      array (
        'key' => 204,
        'id' => '299',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Transfer/Promote/Change Job Permanent',
      ),
      205 => 
      array (
        'key' => 205,
        'id' => '298',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Transfer/Promote/Change Job Temporary',
      ),
      206 => 
      array (
        'key' => 206,
        'id' => '91',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Reporting , Data & Analytics',
      ),
      207 => 
      array (
        'key' => 207,
        'id' => 'TBC',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learn More',
      ),
      208 => 
      array (
        'key' => 208,
        'id' => '304',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'My Teams\' Information',
      ),
      209 => 
      array (
        'key' => 209,
        'id' => '303',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Workday Reporting',
      ),
      210 => 
      array (
        'key' => 210,
        'id' => '87',
        'level' => '2',
        'name' => 'Talent, Performance & Development',
      ),
      211 => 
      array (
        'key' => 211,
        'id' => '290',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Learning',
      ),
      212 => 
      array (
        'key' => 212,
        'id' => '291',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Performance & Development',
      ),
      213 => 
      array (
        'key' => 213,
        'id' => '292',
        'level' => '3',
        'name' => 'Talent',
      )
    )
```

Comment: It's generally better to use `var_export()` when you have code you want others to run, and `var_dump()` when you're inspecting an object. It's tedious to get back to the original array and try things using a `var_dump()`

Comment: cool, i'll update the full array with export :)

Comment: added the full array now.

Comment: Bummer, work is over for today... I'll lose sleep over this little bugger :(

Answer (score 2):

You can try use PHP links [operator &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930177/phps-operator), try somthing like this:

```
 $collection = array();
    $list = yourArray[];
    foreach ($list as $item) {
      if (isset($list[$item['key']])) {
        $list[$item['key']]['levels'][$item['key']] =& $list[$item['key']];
      } else {
         $collection[$item['key']] =& $list[$item['key']];
      }
    }
```

Second variant

```
$row = array();
if (is_array($source) && !empty($source)) {
    foreach ($source as $item) {
        if (!isset($row[$item['level']])) {
            $row[$item['level']] = array($item['level']);
            $row[$item['level']]['parent'] = $item['level'] - 1;
        }
        if(isset($row[$item['level']])){
            $row[$item['level']]['child'][$item['key']] = $item;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($row)){
        foreach($row as $rowK => $rowV){
            if(isset($row[$rowV['parent']])){
                $row[$rowV['parent']]['level-' . $rowK][] =& $row[$rowK];
            } else {
                $collection[$rowK] =& $row[$rowK];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: boy, this is way over my head. I wouldn't even know how to change it if it doesn't work :p

Comment: Sory but it's very simple way))

Comment: I'm a front end guy :) I thought I could do php, but if this simple heh. Cheers for helping out though. so `$list` is the big array. I'm `print_r($collection)` and its empty... Doing it all wrong?

Comment: Ok try to change: if (isset($list[$item['level']])) {
        $list[$item['key']]['levels'][$item['key']] =& $list[$item['id']];
      } else {
         $collection[$item['key']] =& $list[$item['key']];
      }

Comment: index id change on index key everywhere

Comment: Sorry, i'm not giving you anything back, but its still return `array (
)`. I've added the full array if that might help? :)

Comment: humm, i'm getting `*RECURSION*` between each item?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27959/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-imrch)

Comment: if you see  *RECURSION* it's right. Try use <pre>print_r($collection)</pre>

Comment: ye, used that. Now the output it 8.8mb's :) There should only be around 215 fields, dying to give you the correct answer and a upcote :)

Comment: if(isset($collection[$item['level']])){
        $collection[$item['level']][] =& $list[$item['key']];
    } else {
        $collection[$item['level']][] =& $list[$item['key']];
    }

Comment: I don't understand what index is the relation between items of array? If it level use code upper this comment

Comment: Cheers again for helping... saving my life. 
Can we move it here? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27959/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-imrch

Comment: If wont to build tree view you need to add some index witch make relation betwen row elements, like parent, after you can make tree view

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with... It's not a quite efficient approach, but maybe somebody could turn it into a fancy recursive function to make it abstract - I've tried a little, but I really suck at recursions :-P

```
function cascade_array ($array, $current_level = 1) {

    // filter only the array elements with the level==current_level
    $chunks = array_filter ($array, function ($v) use ($current_level) { 
        return $v['level'] == 1; } 
    );

    // extract the keys from those elements an put them in reverse order
    $splice_keys = array_reverse(array_keys($chunks));

    // now splice the array at those keys and put the 
    // array-parts in a result-array, so you have an array of e.g. all level1
    foreach ($splice_keys as $offset) {

            $results[] = array_splice($array, $offset);
    }

    //now walk through the results and basically do the same
    foreach($results as &$level) {

        $level[0]['children'] = array();

        $array = array_splice($level, 1);
        $chunks = array_filter ($array, function ($v) use ($current_level) {  
            return $v['level'] == 2; } 
        );  
        $splice_keys = array_reverse(array_keys($chunks));

        foreach($splice_keys as $offset) {

            $level[0]['children'][] = array_splice($array, $offset);

        }


        foreach($level[0]['children'] as &$child_level) {

            $child_level[0]['children'] = array();

            $array = array_splice($child_level, 1);
            $chunks = array_filter ($array, function ($v) use ($current_level) {

                return $v['level'] == 3; } 
            );  
            $splice_keys = array_reverse(array_keys($chunks));

            foreach($splice_keys as $offset) {

                $child_level[0]['children'][] = array_splice($array, $offset);

            }

        }

    }

    return $results;

}
```

The code is actually pretty straight forward, I guess. Here's a working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kb5JBc - I hope it helps :)

Comment: argh, definitely the closest I've come to getting it correct :) Trouble is its ended up with 2748 lines, it shouldn't be creating any new rows you see. It should only be moving the entries into their respective parents... Not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: @JamieHutber I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you mean... What exactly are rows/lines in this context? Could you give an example output-array (not in pseudo code)? And what exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe knowing the main goal might help, e.g. what do you want to do with the (transformed) data and how?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive entities are never easy, especially if you are starting out with PHP.

The following is a short function that avoids the need for using a recursive function by using php references instead. References can be confusing, as can recursion. The best advice is to read up and try a few things out in order to work out how they behave.

The following works using a stack that keeps track of the levels, and keeps referring back to the last level to find the latest parent.

```
function stackItems( $items ){
  $level = 0;
  $return = array();
  $stack = array(&$return);
  foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
    while ( $level >= $item['level'] ) {
      unset($stack[$level--]);
    }
    $parent = &$stack[$level];
    if ( !isset($parent['children']) ) {
      $parent['children'] = array();
    }
    $parent['children'][] = &$items[$key];
    if ( $item['level'] > $level ) {
      $level = $item['level'];
      $stack[$level] = &$items[$key];
    }
  }
  return $return['children'];
}
```

With comments version:

```
function stackItems( $items ){
  $level = 0;
  $return = array();
  /// build our stack with our return array as first item
  $stack = array(&$return);
  /// step each item
  foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
    /// if our next item is lower down than current 
    /// level, drop the stack down.
    while ( $level >= $item['level'] ) {
      /// we may as well unset to clear memory
      unset($stack[$level--]);
    }
    /// create a shortcut reference to our parent on the stack
    $parent = &$stack[$level];
    /// to avoid warnings create the children array first
    if ( !isset($parent['children']) ) {
      $parent['children'] = array();
    }
    /// now add ourselves to the current parent on the stack
    $parent['children'][] = &$items[$key];
    /// if our current item is higher level than current, add to
    /// the stack ready to be treated as the next parent.
    if ( $item['level'] > $level ) {
      /// level ourselves to the current item
      $level = $item['level'];
      /// store in the stack a reference to item
      $stack[$level] = &$items[$key];
    }
  }
  /// return the first set of children as there seems
  /// to be only one level 1 item.
  return $return['children'];
}
```

Comment: Sounds awesome :) I got this when running the file: `Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Users\jch80204\www\TranslationsMega\index.php on line 149`

Comment: You know that there shouldn't be any new entities created? As in, still only 250 or there abouts? I'm so bad at explaining things :(

Comment: @JamieHutber the above worked on my local setup, rendering the page well before 30 seconds had taken place. Are you running this on a larger dataset than in your question? If so you'll have to be careful with regards to time taken and memory usage. Might be best to run the new structure formation in batches of level ones.

Comment: no worries then :) I'll increase the time and its slightly bigger, 341 rows rather than 250ish. But i'm also using a rather IMO install of Xampp as I'm on a work machine and we don't use php here. Just wanted it for this :)

Comment: @JamieHutber Hmm. well you shouldn't get too much of a problem with only a 100 more rows :) but it does depend on the speed of the machine. Upping the execution time could work... this error might be an indicator that something else is wrong however.