# Trying to understand &$signature parameter in openssl_sign

Tags: php, php-openssl

I'm trying to understand -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php which has `&$signature` parameter. I read this -> [PHP &$string - What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419613/php-string-what-does-this-mean) but still don't understand why must we have `&$signature` as a parameter or how do we use it. The examples at https://www.php.net did not describe the use of that variable.

Here's one of their examples.

```
<?php
// $data is assumed to contain the data to be signed

// fetch private key from file and ready it
$pkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://src/openssl-0.9.6/demos/sign/key.pem");

// compute signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $pkeyid);

// free the key from memory
openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
?>
```

Btw, have a fabulous coding new year 2022!

Answer (score 0):

Function 'openssl_sign' is defined to computes a signature which is passed by reference.

Without '&', parameter signature won't change after the function is called.

Comment: Why do we want to change the signature? I mean why pass it as parameter to the function?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass vars by reference to a function so the function can modify the variable directly without returning value.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php