# Why am I getting an "unexpected token &" here?

Tags: php

My PHP syntax highlighter / intellisense is telling me that the `&` of `&$cases` in the line

```
$thisTable = $work_type === WorkTypes::Study ? &$cases : &$projs);
```

is an unexpected token. What I'm trying to do is create an alias for either my `$cases` or `$projs` object depending on whether `$work_type === WorkTypes::Study`.

Comment: You have a `)` but no `(`

Comment: @AbraCadaver That was a type-o on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlighter is right: the reference operator does not work inside a ternary operator because the `=&` is atomic (although the spaces don't seem to matter too much). Use this instead:

```
$work_type === WorkTypes::Study ? $thisTable = &$cases : $thisTable = &$projs;
```

(and as others have mentioned: either no brackets or both)

See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488768/2286722).

Comment: Thanks! It appears that this bit of code is what was causing my entire page to not renderr.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works, please mark the answer as accepted (see also [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis:

```
$thisTable = ($work_type === WorkTypes::Study ? &$cases : &$projs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a missing `(` bracket could kill you, happens to the best of us.

```
$thisTable = ($work_type === WorkTypes::Study ? &$cases : &$projs);
```