# Partial page import with FPDF/FPDI

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

It was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037429/how-to-delete-text-from-pdf-using-fpdi-fpdf) if it was possible to delete text from an existing PDF using FPDI but it seems it isn't.

So, is there a way to partially import a page with FPDI. That is, only import, let's say, the last half of an existing PDF's page?

```
$pdf = new Fpdi;
$pageId = $pdf->ImportPage($pageNo);
$pdf->AddPage('P', "Letter");
$pdf->useImportedPage($pageId); // Import only the lower half of this page since I don't need the upper half...
```

Answer (score 0):

The general answer from the developer FAQ is

> "Can I edit or modify a PDF document with FPDI?

Simple and correct answer:

> No FPDI extracts and imports single pages of existing documents into a structure which can be re-used by FPDF. The resulting PDF created by FPDF/FPDI is a completely new document. Please don't misunderstand: with FPDI you cannot edit a PDF document."

and related

> "It is impossible to explicity exclude or include content of a layer."

So unless somebody has developed a supporting page redaction ability, all FPDI does is import (copy) a whole page of contents but without some of the associated links. Note according to comment by Jan Slabon of Setasign since version 2.4 the pages external links may be retained.

> Since FPDI 2.4.0 link annotations with an URI action are imported if the $importExternalLinks parameter of the importPage() method is set to true.

Comment: It's FPDI not FPDF (last sentence) and as you mentioned "associated links": external links are supported as of version 2.4, too.

Comment: Yours is fine but the last sentence :-) The link to the manual shows common limitations and not abilities.